# Test not being picked up by code coverage (c# .net standard)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq, code-coverage

I've implemented my own logger, which follows the ILogger interface.  Internally, it has the AppInsights Client and that's what my logger actually logs to.  Here's a simplified version of my class:

```
public class AppInsightsLogger : ILogger
{
    internal TelemetryClient Client { get; set; }

    public AppInsightsLogger(string instrumentationKey)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
        Client = new TelemetryClient();
    }

    public void Log<T>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, T state, Exception exception,
        Func<T, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventId.Name))
        {
            StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1); 
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            var type = method.DeclaringType;
            var name = method.Name;

            eventId = new EventId(eventId.Id == 0 ? BitConverter.ToInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), 0) : eventId.Id, $"{type}:{name}");
        }

        var props = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "EventId", eventId.Id.ToString() },
            { "EventName", eventId.Name }
        };

        var telemetry = new EventTelemetry(eventId.Name);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.ToString()))
        {
            telemetry.Properties.Add("SummaryMessage", state.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var property in props)
        {
            telemetry.Properties.Add(property);
        }

        Client.TrackEvent(telemetry);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to verify (potentially wrongly, please also advise), is that when I call my `AppInsightsLogger` classes `Log` method that it actually attempts to call the TelemetryClient's TrackEvent method.  I was thinking of a test like this:

```
    [Fact, IsUnit]
    public void Test_Telemetry_Log()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();

        mock.Setup(m => 
             m.Log<string>(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null, null));

        mock.Object.Log(LogLevel.Information, new EventId(1, "test"), "test", null, null);

        mock.Verify();
    }
```

BUT when I run this test (which passes fine), it doesn't appear as covered by my code coverage monitor (Jetbrain's *dotCoverage*).

[image]

Any ideas how I perform this test correctly so I'm covering the code correctly?  I'm also using **Moq**.

Is the problem because it's a mocked instance?  I cant mock the TelemetryClient as my other thought to testing this was an instances of AppInsightsLogger and then verifying the TelemetryClient.log is called BUT it's a sealed class which complicates this test :-/

Thanks in advance for any tips!!
NOTE: I'm fairly new to writing tests - I understand the concepts but not actually carrying out.

Comment: The code coverage monitor is right: you are mocking the class you are testing and the actual implementation is never run. Rather than mocking `ILogger` what you  want to do is call the Log method on a real instance of `AppInsightsLogger` and mock the `TelemetryClient` instead.

Comment: TelemetryClient is a sealed class though :( but that makes sense that it's the mocked instance - not sure how to test this

Comment: encapsulate/wrap the telemetry client behind an abstraction you control and have that injected into the logger. The logger is too tightly coupled to implementation concerns which make it difficult to unit test in isolation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your code is not covered because it's not executed. You set up a mock object and than called a method on this set up. Instead of your real code the moq kicks in and just returns the values you set up.

So when you call:

```
mock.Object.Log(LogLevel.Information, new EventId(1, "test"), "test", null, null);
```

it's not going into the code, it looks for matching set ups on your mock object and finds one:

```
mock.Setup(m => 
             m.Log<string>(It.IsAny<LogLevel>(), It.IsAny<EventId>(), It.IsAny<string>(), null, null));
```

In your test you should in fact instantiate your AppInsightsLogger and call log on it. Hide your TelemetryClient behind an interface, mock that, and than verify. Not going into details it will look sth like this:

```
public interface ITelemetryClientWrapper{
 void TrackEvent();
}

public class MyTelemetryClient : ITelemetryClientWrapper{
 public void TrackEvent(){
   // Use real TelemetryClient here, I guess it's not your class, right? If it's your class, just extract an interface from it
 }
}
```

Inject it to your Logger in constructor or property (use DI):

```
public class MyLogger{
  public MyLogger(ITelemetryClientWrapper wrapper){
  }
}
```

And finally in your test:

```
var telemetryMock = new Mock<ITelemetryClientWrapper>();
var target = new MyLogger(telemetryMock.Object);
target.Log(...);

telemetryMock.Verify(c => c.TrackEvent());
```

To cut it short: you don't mock the class you test, you mock the dependencies of this class. So that when you test your class, code from other classes don't run and don't influence your test results.